# not a valid identifier error with read command

Tags: linux, bash

I have looked into reading files from this site, man pages and google but not understanding, I apologize if this has been answered. I am having trouble reading a file into my script. I am using bash shell in linux. I am also new to linux.

I have a script that is supposed to read from a text file, perform tests, calculations, etc on each of the data lines specified.

I am getting the following error: ./hw-script7b: line 8: read: `hw7.list3': not a valid identifier
the hw7.list3 is the input file. it has full rights (read, write, even execute) hw-script7b is my script.

the text file contains an -ls listing of a directory. this is probably a basic issue but I am lost.
thanks for any assistance,

Debbie

here is the script.

```
echo "start"
count=0     #counting all files
xcount=0    #counting executeable files
total=0     #counting total space used
temp=0      #holding place for file being checked

exec 9< $1
while read $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 0<&9
do
count='expr $count + 1'
if [ $4 > "$temp" ]
then
lfname="$8"
linode="$1"
lsize="$4"
lrights="$2"
lmonth="$5" 
lday="$6"
temp="$4"
else
 if [ $4 < "$temp" ]
 then
 sfname="$8"
 sinode="$1"
 ssize="$4"
 srights="$2"
 smonth="$5"
 sday="$6"
 temp="$4"
 fi
fi

#looking for executeable files
if [ -x "$8" ]
then
xcount='expr $xcount + 1'
fi
done

echo "The largest file is: "$lfile""
echo "      Inode    Size    Rights       Date     "
echo "     $linode  $lsize  $lrights  $lmonth $lday"
echo
echo
echo "The smallest file is: "$sfile""
echo "      Inode    Size    Rights       Date     "
echo "     $sinode  $ssize  $srights  $smonth $sday"
echo
echo
echo "The total number of files is "$count" and they use "$total" bytes."
echo
echo
echo "There are "$xcount" executable files."
exit 0


sample of input file: hw7.list3
934250 -rwxrwxr-x 1 1107 Dec  2 18:48 //home/others/professor/class-share/hw7.howard
7934314 -r-xr-xr-t 1 1232 Dec  2 18:48 //home/others/professor/class-share/Matts_HW6
7934139 -rwxrwxr-x 1 1232 Dec  4 20:08 //home/others/professor/class-share/Matts_HW6_2
7934366 -rwxrw-r-- 1 1537 Dec  9 19:32 //home/others/professor/class-share/bs-hw7
7934364 -rwx------ 1  965 Dec  9 19:48 //home/others/professor/class-share/hw7
7948204 -rwxr-xr-x 1 107 Nov 12 07:47 readtest1
7948209 -rwxr-xr-x 1 107 Nov 12 07:48 readtest1a
7948205 -rwxr-xr-x 1 140 Nov 12 07:48 readtest2
7948206 -rwxr-xr-x 1 160 Nov 12 07:48 readtest3
7948207 -rwxr-xr-x 1 165 Nov 12 07:48 readtest4
7948208 -rwxr-xr-x 1 211 Nov 12 07:48 readtest5
7948210 -rwxr-xr-x 1   8 Nov 12 07:49 namefile1
7948211 -rwxr-xr-x 1  17 Nov 12 07:49 namefile2
7948212 -rwxr-xr-x 1  28 Nov 12 07:49 namefile3
7932451 -rwxr--r-- 1  219 Nov 13 16:53 //home/others/professor/class-share/grades-text
7934113 -rw-r--r-- 1  111 Nov 18 17:27 //home/others/professor/class-share/test2.gz
```

Comment: I ws not sure if we can post the script. I have posted. The file I am reading form is a ls -il text file of a directory. I had it called hw7.list3 but the comment below mentioned the dot may cause issues so I renamed it hw7list3. Now I don't get the error but nothing outputs. researching more.

Comment: Are you assuming that `read foo` will read from a file called `foo`? It won't; it reads from stdin (typically the keyboard) into a *variable* called `$foo`. There's little point in having a variable with the same name as a file. What are you trying to do?

Comment: We just learned that you can redirect the stdin to grab info from a file instead of the keyboard. We need to use this file and find the largest file, smallest file and calculate the space used and number of files. There are a few other things we need to do as well. I can't seem to read the file into the variables, even though I seem to have it setup like the examples in class.

Comment: [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is a good place for folks to start with this general class of problem.

Answer (score 7):

I faced a similar issue while running one of my scripts. My script displays the running process ids and prompts the user to enter one of the process ids. I got this error
': not a valid identifier: read: `userPid

This is due to some special characters which gets added to the script when we scp the script from windows to unix.
I did the following and it worked fine.
sudo yum install dos2unix
dos2unix script_file.sh
Then ran the script.  It worked without issues.

Comment: had the same issue - was the CRLF - needed to set it to just CR as unixoid systems use it.

Comment: Thanks! this dos2unix thing worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error. I was editing on notepad++. If you're doing the same thing, covert the eof character to the one for linux (lf)

Answer (score 3):

**Most cases for `': not a valid identifier:` due some special characters in script**

Make sure that your editor support shell script command,better avoid windows editors. Try use pico/vi/gedit in linux

this may help some one with same problem.

Comment: Not at all the case here, though; the problem in this case is caused by passing a filename (which isn't also a valid variable name) as an argument to `read`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is you're doing `read $variable` and not `read variable` Try it without the $ symbol and it should work like a charm.

Comment: It's also an issue that `$1` isn't a regular variable that be assigned to (without using `set --` to establish a whole new argument list). So this is getting closer to the problem, but it's not really sufficient in and of itself.

Comment: scythe and Charles Duffy has formed the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that should get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
count=0     #counting all files
xcount=0    #counting executeable files
total=0     #counting total space used
temp=0      #holding place for file being checked


while read linode lrights dummy lsize  lmonth lday dummy lfname ;
do
(( count ++ ))
(( total += lsize ))
[[ "$lrights" == *x* ]] && (( xcount ++ ))
done < $1


echo "The total number of files is "$count" and they use "$total" bytes."
echo
echo "There are "$xcount" executable files."
```

I named the script `t.sh`

```
$ ./t.sh hw7.list3 
start
The total number of files is 16 and they use 7346 bytes.

There are 15 executable files.
```

The variables `$1 $2 ...` are set to the arguments given to the script. Here I use `read` to set the variables `linod, etc.` from the contents of the file whose name is given in `$1` (note the `done < $1` part). What you were trying to do is to create a variable named `hw7.list3` which is not possible because it is not a valid Bash variable name ( it contains a dot )

Comment: Thanks, its done a bit different then our class examples, I never saw the done < $1. I am still confused as to how the hw7.list3 was being used as a variable, i thought it was just being read. I will re-edit the program and let you know if it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused from the "End of Line Sequence" LF vs CRLF. It's a setting in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is a VERY old post, but I just discovered the answer

The text file should be saved as UNIX Line Feeds instead of Mac OS CR or Windows CRLF

Answer (score -1):

I know this thread is old, but since there is no chosen solution I'll give it a try.

I had a similar problem as you with a small script, where I wanted the script to read a decimal number as the first command line argument. Got the same error message.

I'm not a bash expert and my solution is probably not very elegant, but I solved my problem by putting a for-command before my while-loop. You could try the same

```
for filename in $*; do
exec 9< $1
while read $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 0<&9
do
count='expr $count + 1'
if [ $4 > "$temp" ]
then

...

done
```

Comment: This is just as buggy as the OP's original code -- it's still trying to pass filenames in a position where only variable names are allowed.

Comment: ...actually, it's **buggier** than the original code -- `for filename in $*`, for instance, will do extremely unfortunate things if any of your filenames passed as arguments contain spaces or can be parsed as globs.